# Installing an SNMP proxy (for a printer)

Tags: networking, printing, configuration, proxy, snmp

I am a newbie to SNMP and its configuration, so my apologies for asking a question that might have a very simple answer. However, I have been searching on the Internet for some time now, and I just cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

### Context:

I have an HP Color Laser Jet Printer which is connected by Ethernet (port 1) to a Device running Ubuntu 16.04 and having two Ethernet ports. From my Windows 10 laptop, which is connected to port 2 of the Linux Device, I want to have SNMP connection with the printer.

For example, I want to be able to ask the OID `1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.5.1.1.1` (hrPrinterStatus.1) from the HP printer (having Static IP `190.168.6.132`) by just sending a SNMP request to my Linux Device (having IP `190.168.6.133` on port 1 and IP `190.168.6.134` on port 2).

### What I did:

I setup as well as an agent as an manager (manager was unnecessary) on the Linux Device as specified [here](http://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-an-snmp-daemon-and-client-on-ubuntu-14-04).

As far as I know, this can simply be solved by using a proxy. This is why I added the line

```
proxy -v 2c -c public 192.168.6.132 .1.3
```

to my `snmpd.conf` file.

However, when I do a SNMP request from my laptop, to my Linux Device. I get:

```
No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
Agent response reported an Error Status of NoSuchName
```

Apparently my SNMP request still looks for the OID at my Linux Device, which isn't a Printer and therefore does not have the OID I am asking for.

### Question:

I am able to do SNMP requests from my Laptop to my Linux Device, and from my Linux Device to my Printer. However, I want the Linux device to just forward the requests to my Printer. I do not want any SNMP requests for asking OIDs from my Linux Device itself, only the Printer. Preferably I would like to just use the 'public' community.
Can anybody help me out? Below you can find the most important part of my current `snmpd.conf` file.

[image: snmpd.conf_1]
[image: snmpd.conf_3]